# sql statement error displaying values

Tags: c#, sql, ado.net

I need help with an sql statement.

I am managing a real estate database. I have a table Properties and multiple tables Bedrooms, Bathrooms etc.

I have a form in which my agent can see in a listbox all the properties, selects the one he likes and it will display the right informations in all the combobox

Each criteria is shown in a combobox. So if you show Property 1 you see : Bedrooms: 1bedroom

Right now my sql statement is:

```
   "SELECT AreaSize.AreaSizeID, AreaSize.DescriptionSurface, Bathrooms.BathroomID, Bathrooms.DescriptionBathroom, Cities.CityID, Cities.DescriptionCities, Prices.PriceID, Prices.DescriptionPrices, Properties.*, Rooms.RoomID, Rooms.DescriptionRooms, Types.TypeID, Types.DescriptionType, Users.* FROM Users INNER JOIN (Types INNER JOIN (Rooms INNER JOIN (Prices INNER JOIN (Cities INNER JOIN (Bathrooms INNER JOIN (AreaSize INNER JOIN Properties ON AreaSize.AreaSizeID = Properties.AreaSize) ON Bathrooms.BathroomID = Properties.Bathrooms) ON Cities.CityID = Properties.City) ON Prices.PriceID = Properties.Price) ON Rooms.RoomID = Properties.Rooms) ON Types.TypeID = Properties.PropertyType) ON Users.UserID = Properties.AgentID WHERE Users.email =@email";
```

How I display in a combobox:

```
cboBedrooms.Text = tbListing.Rows[idx]["DescriptionRooms"].ToString();
```

> The problem is that right now it only shows the value of the property selected and not all the other values.
>
> > if i am in property 2, combobox for bedrooms shows only: 2 bedrooms  
> >     ­­­­ it should show: 2 bedrooms, than you click on the arrow and shows 1 bedroom

```
+-----------------------------------------+
|    Properties                           |
+------------+------------+---------------+
| PropertyID | NbBedrooms | AgentID...    |
| 1          | 1          |  2...         |
| 2          | 2          |   1...        |
+------------+------------+------------+
```

```
+-------------------------+
|    Bedrooms             |
+------------+------------+
| PropertyID | NbBedrooms |
| 1          | 1bedroom   |
| 2          | 2bedrooms  |
+------------+------------+
```

Answer (score 1):

Your issue is that you are only setting the text of the `ComboBox` and not the actual items collection from which you can select. To achieve this simply loop through your `DataTable` object and add a new item to the `ComboBox` for each option.

```
foreach (DataRow row in tbListing.Rows)
{
    cboBedrooms.Items.Add(row["DescriptionRooms"].ToString();
}
```

Then once you've filled the `Items` collection you can set the `SelectedItem` property of the `ComboBox` equal to the currently set value for the property to show your user what the value is before they potentially make a change.

So if your loop were to go through and fill your `ComboBox` with values `A, B, C, D` and you wanted to set the selected value to `B` you would simply do:

```
cboBedrooms.SelectedItem = "B";
```

To go an extra step farther you'll probably want to write back to your database the new value your user selected if they want to make a change. To grab the selected value of the `ComboBox` you can simply use the same `SelectedItem` property with `.ToString()` suffixing it in your case.

*Note: The `SelectedItem` property gets and sets a type of `object`. Seeing as you're only using strings it is okay to do a simple `.ToString()` to fetch the selected value but in the case you would want to use more complex objects you would have to first cast to that object and then retrieve the value.*